# Is there a cross platform way to detect debug mode compilation?

Tags: c++, c++11, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a cross platform way to detect debug mode compilation?  If not, then how to do it for the top compilers; MSVC, GNU & MINGW, mac, clang, intel.

For example MSVC you can detect debug mode like the following.

```
#if defined _DEBUG
// debug related stuff here
#else
// release related stuff here
#endif
```

Comment: The standard says that if `NDEBUG` is defined, then the definition of `assert` will be nothing (which effectively means "release mode"). You might be able to check `#ifndef NDEBUG` to get the wanted behaviour.

Comment: Debug and release builds aren't well defined outside of MSVC. Why not ask whoever is using your code to define something for when they're debugging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For many or most compilers, "debug" mode is a multifaceted concept that includes several orthogonal settings.  For example, with `gcc`, you can add debugging symbols to the output code using `-g`, enable optimizations using `-O`, or disable `assert()` macros using `-DNDEBUG` (to define the `NDEBUG` macro).  In my work, we have deployed production code with many combinations of these enabled or disabled.  We have left `-g` on in order to attach to running processes and troubleshoot them using `gdb` (in which case we usually have to fight with the spaghetti `-O` produced), left assertions on to get more information about persistent errors across releases, and disabled optimizations for legacy codebases written under a more permissive interpretation of "undefined behavior" (until we could fix/replace it).

Since the `NDEBUG` macro actually affects the semantics of the generated code (and some libraries change their ABIs when the macro is defined or not), that's probably the most portable answer to your question.  However, if you're using that macro to detect optimized builds portably, you'll probably have mixed success.

Answer (score -1):

Below code should be work:

```cpp
#ifdef defined DEBUG || defined _DEBUG

#else

#endif
```